# How can Windows be prevented from automatically redoing a search in the Search Results window?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, search

The problem I have with it is that when you perform a search, Windows keeps spontaneously redoing the search. It seems that the most likely cause is when a file in the list is renamed or deleted (though that is not a reliable way to reproduce it).

This is extremely frustrating because the renamed/deleted file is already updated in the list, and even if there were a reason to update it, then the user can easily click the *Search Now* button. In other words, I can't figure out a rational reason for Windows to forcibly do it automatically. Worse, no matter how many times *Stop Search* is clicked, it expertly ignores the user’s wishes (and direct actions) and keeps doing it. Even closing the Search pane altogether does not convince Windows to knock it off.

I cannot find any search-related settings. Does anyone know of a way to prevent Windows from spontaneously redoing the search on its own?

(For the record, I have the indexing service disabled.)

Comment: If you turn the the Indexing on, it may refresh quicker. :)

Comment: I don’t/won’t use Windows indexing. Besides, I don’t want it to refresh on its own **at all**.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to stop search indexing service as it might update the search results each time the index update affects the directory you are searching in (just a wild guess) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621736

Comment: The indexing service is disabled.